# how can I leave single <br> tag for the output string from the input string with multiple <br> tags in a row, sanitize-html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-sanitizing

I have an issue, related to the sanitize-html library, here's my code:

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';


const allowedTags = [
  'h1',
  'h2',
  'h3',
  'h4',
  'h5',
  'p',
  'a',
  'strong',
  'i',
  'ul',
  'ol',
  'li',
  'em',
  'br',
];
export const sanitizeEventDescription = (
  description: string,
  keepNewline: boolean
) =>
  sanitizeHtml(description, {
    allowedTags,
    transformTags: {
      a: function transform(tagName, attribs) {
        const href = href

        return {
          tagName: 'a',
          attribs: {
            ...attribs,
            href,
            target: '_blank',
            rel: 'noopener noreferrer',
          },
        };
      },
    },
    exclusiveFilter(frame) {
      return !frame.text.trim() && frame.tag !== 'br';
    },
    textFilter(text) {
      return text.replace(/(\n|<br>)+/g, '<br>').replace(/<br><br>/g, '<br>');
    },
  });
```

When I provide an input string with consecutive `\n` characters, the textFilter function replaces them with a single `<br>` tag as expected. However, when I provide an input string with consecutive `<br>` tags, the textFilter function doesn't seem to collapse them as intended. Instead, I still get multiple `<br>` tags in a row in the output.

For example, if I pass in the input string `"testing carriage <br><br>returns."`, I still get multiple `<br>` tags in a row in the output. However, if I pass in the input string `"testing carriage \n\nreturns."`, I get a single `<br>` tag in the output.

I've tried adding `<br>` to the allowedTags constant and modifying the exclusiveFilter function to include `frame.tag !== 'br'`, but this only allows `<br>` tags to be outputted and doesn't seem to help with collapsing consecutive `<br>` tags.

Can anyone explain why the textFilter function isn't collapsing multiple `<br>` tags in a row and how I can modify my code to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Use single `\`` characters to warp your `<br>` in text to avoid layout issues. (I tried to edit your post but you were editing at the same time so it was canceled)

Comment: thank you and sorry for that!

Comment: Text isn’t html, it’s text. I don’t know how to disable multiple valid tags though.

Comment: it's my example, in practice I have html

Comment: Do you have an example `description` which produces an undesired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sanitize-html doesn't provide functionality to remove consecutive 
 tags or \n, so the good option here is to prevent getting the string with consecutive 
 tags first like this:

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';


const allowedTags = [
  'h1',
  'h2',
  'h3',
  'h4',
  'h5',
  'p',
  'a',
  'strong',
  'i',
  'ul',
  'ol',
  'li',
  'em',
  'br',
];
export const sanitizeEventDescription = (
  description: string,
  keepNewline: boolean
) =>
  sanitizeHtml(description.replace(/(<br\s?\/?>|\n)\s*(<br\s?\/?>|\n)+/gim, '<br>'), {
    allowedTags,
    transformTags: {
      a: function transform(tagName, attribs) {
        const href = href

        return {
          tagName: 'a',
          attribs: {
            ...attribs,
            href,
            target: '_blank',
            rel: 'noopener noreferrer',
          },
        };
      },
    },
    exclusiveFilter(frame) {
      return !frame.text.trim() && frame.tag !== 'br';
    },
    textFilter(text) {
      return text.replace(/(\n|<br>)+/g, '<br>').replace(/<br><br>/g, '<br>');
    },
  });
```